# seven days in a week

Tags: tanach

Is there any proof apart from the bible and creation that a week has seven days. Like is there proof from the planets. And if not why does the whole world even those who had never seen the bible count a week as being seven days.

Comment: I must be grossly misunderstanding your question; isn’t the first chapter plus of Genesis a proof that a week is seven days? What exactly is your question? Can you please [edit] to clarify?

Comment: I thought my question was simple for those who didnt have the bible or those who dont believe in it. Most people dont believe in creation today.

Comment: Then why is this question asked on a site for those who base their lives on Judaism and all that that entails?

Comment: DonielF You are right. But I am sorry to say that today most Jewish people dont believe in creation although they keep shabbos and new year which are dependent on it. I was proving the fallacy of it.

Answer (score 1):

> why does the whole world even those who had never seen the bible count a week as being seven days.

Problem is, they didn't (my emphasis):

> An **eight**-day week was used in Ancient Rome and possibly in the pre-Christian Celtic calendar. Traces of a **nine**-day week are found in Baltic languages and in Welsh. The ancient Chinese calendar had a **ten**-day week, as did the ancient Egyptian calendar (…)
>
> A **six**-day week is found in the Akan Calendar. Several cultures used a **five**-day week, including the 10th century Icelandic calendar, the Javanese calendar, and the traditional cycle of market days in Korea. The Igbo have a "market week" of **four** days. Evidence of a "**three**-day week" has been derived from the names of the days of the week in Guipuscoan Basque.
>
> The Aztecs and Mayas used (…) weeks of **13** days (known in Spanish as trecenas).

*[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Pre-modern_calendars)*

Comment: Maybe a better question is why and how everyone in the world agrees on what day of the week it is now.

Comment: You are right. But considering there were so many different days in a week why today does everyone have seven. What made everybody change their minds.

Answer (score 0):

The Babylonians associated one day with each of the seven easily observed astronomical bodies, i.e., sun, moon, and five visible planets: Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn.

Comment: I also saw this on google but find it a very flimsy reason. Who said there had to be a week anyway. Why did they need to make one.